# For loop to print out UTF doesn't terminate

Tags: java, for-loop, unicode, char

I am fairly new to coding and stumbled upon a problem.

I wanted to print out and see the characters and what number they have by following:

```java
for(char i = 20488; i <= 90000; i++) {
    int x = i;
    System.out.print(x + " = ");
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

the last couple outputs before i ended it were:

```
7259 = ᱛ
7260 = ᱜ
7261 = ᱝ
7262 = ᱞ
7263 = ᱟ
7264 = ᱠ
```

What seems to be the problem?

I expected everything to be printed till 90.000

Comment: You might want to look at what the maximum value for a char is. It doesn't go as high as 90000. That's why your `char i` will eventually overflow and your condition `i <= 90000` will never be false.

Comment: Upon googling i can not find anything other than 256, but i can print it till at least 30.000

Comment: You need to look at the Unicode tables

Comment: Check the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html) in section 4.2.1

Comment: @CodeRattlesnake There is no need for google. The primitiv Data types and there values are described in official documentation and tutorials: [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) - And there is also a java class Character that has that information saved as a static field: `Character.MAX_VALUE` (So doing `System.out.println((int) Character.MAX_VALUE);` will print you the max value as a number

Comment: Awesome! Got it! Thank you very much @OHGODSPIDERS and Rifat

Comment: How do i mark my question as solved?

Comment: You could accept one of the answers below, or add your own answer and check that as correct.  (You might need some more points for the latter, I'm not sure if there's a cut off to be able to do that.  If not, you can just leave it as is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will notice that if you put this code in an IDE, or perhaps through a compiler with the correct warnings enabled, you'll get this warning:

> Condition 'i <= 90000' is always 'true'

It's telling you that a `char` doesn't go as high as `90000`. So your loop will never end.

A `char` can go from [`MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_VALUE) (`'\u0000'`) to [`MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE) (`'\uFFFF'`). That’s 0 to 65,535 in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid `char`

The [Answer by Jorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77309597/642706) is correct, and should be accepted.

Let me add that `char` has been essentially broken since Java 2 and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` (& its wrapper class [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html)) is physically incapable of representing most characters.

Instead of `char`, use [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers to work with individual characters.

### Code point

Code points range from zero to just over a million. About 150,000 of that million have been assigned to a character by the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium). The rest are either reserved for future use or set aside for “private” use.

Use `static` methods on the `Character` class to inspect each code point.

```
for( int codePoint = Character.MIN_CODE_POINT ; codePoint <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT ; codePoint ++ )
{
    if ( Character.isDefined ( codePoint ) ) 
    {
        String name = Character.getName( codePoint) ;
        String character = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
        … 
    }
}
```

You will find other code point methods on classes like `String`, `StringBuilder`, etc.